# asyncio/aiohttp - create_task() blocks event loop, gather results in "This event loop is already running "

Tags: python, python-asyncio, coroutine, aiohttp, event-loop

I cannot get both my consumer and my producer running at the same time, it seems worker(), or the aiohttp server are blocking - even when executed simultaneously with asyncio.gather()

If instead I do loop.create_task(worker), this will block and server will never be started.

I've tried every variation I can imagine, including nest_asyncio module - and I can only ever get one of the two components running.

What am I doing wrong?

```
async def worker():
    batch_size = 30

    print("running worker")
    while True:
        if queue.qsize() > 0:
            future_map = {}

            size = min(queue.qsize(), batch_size)
            batch = []
            for _ in range(size):
                item = await queue.get()
                print("Item: "+str(item))
                future_map[item["fname"]] = item["future"]
                batch.append(item)

            print("processing", batch)
            results = await process_files(batch)
            for dic in results:
                for key, value in dic.items():
                    print(str(key)+":"+str(value))
                    future_map[key].set_result(value)

            # mark the tasks done
            for _ in batch:
                queue.task_done()



def start_worker():
    loop.create_task(worker())

def create_app():
    app = web.Application()
    routes = web.RouteTableDef()
    @routes.post("/decode")
    async def handle_post(request):
        return await decode(request)
    app.add_routes(routes)
    app.on_startup.append(start_worker())
    return app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    app = create_app()
    web.run_app(app)
```

The above prints "running worker" and does not start the AIOHTTP server.

```
def run(loop, app, port=8001):
handler = app.make_handler()
f = loop.create_server(handler, '0.0.0.0', port)
srv = loop.run_until_complete(f)
print('serving on', srv.sockets[0].getsockname())
try:
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    loop.run_until_complete(handler.finish_connections(1.0))
    srv.close()
    loop.run_until_complete(srv.wait_closed())
    loop.run_until_complete(app.finish())
loop.close()

def main(app):
    asyncio.gather(run(loop, app), worker())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    app = create_app()
    main(app)
```

The above starts server, but not the worker.

Comment: It looks like `worker` only awaits something when the queue isn't empty. It's going to block anything else from running, including whatever pushes things onto the queue. Adding something like `await asyncio.sleep(0)` when the queue is empty would probably help. (Adjust the sleep time accordingly.)

Comment: That seemed to do it, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although `await asyncio.sleep(0)` fixes the immediate issue, it's not an ideal fix; in fact, it's somewhat of an anti-pattern. To understand why, let's examine why the problem occurs in more detail. The heart of the matter is the worker's `while` loop - as soon as the queue becomes empty, it effectively boils down to:

```
while True:
    pass
```

Sure, the part marked as `pass` contains a check for `qsize()` leading to execution of additional code if the queue is non-empty, but once `qsize()` first reaches 0, that check will always evaluate to false. This is because asyncio is single-threaded and when `qsize() == 0` the, the `while` loop no longer encounters a single `await`. Without `await`, it's impossible to relinquish control to a coroutine or callback that might populate the queue, and the `while` loop becomes infinite.

This is why `await asyncio.sleep(0)` inside the loop helps: it forces a context switch, guaranteeing that other coroutines will get a chance to run and eventually re-populate the queue. However, it also keeps the `while` loop constantly running, which means that the event loop will never go to sleep, even if the queue remains empty for hours on end. The event loop will remain in a busy-waiting state for as long as the worker is active. You could alleviate the busy-wait by adjusting the sleep interval to a non-zero value, as suggested by dirn, but that will introduce latency, and will still not allow the event loop to go to sleep when there's no activity.

The proper fix is to *not* check for `qsize()`, but to use `queue.get()` to get the next item. This will sleep as long as needed until the item appears, and immediately wake up the coroutine once it does. Don't worry that this will "block" the worker - it's precisely the point of asyncio that you can have multiple coroutines and that one being "blocked" on an await simply allows others to proceed. For example:

```
async def worker():
    batch_size = 30

    while True:
        # wait for an item and add it to the batch
        batch = [await queue.get()]
        # batch up more items if available
        while not queue.empty() and len(batch) < batch_size:
            batch.append(await queue.get())
        # process the batch
        future_map = {item["fname"]: item["future"] for item in batch}
        results = await process_files(batch)
        for dic in results:
            for key, value in dic.items():
                print(str(key)+":"+str(value))
                future_map[key].set_result(value)
        for _ in batch:
            queue.task_done()
```

In this variant we await for something in every iteration of the loop, and sleeping is not needed.

Comment: Thank you for the full explanation. Accepted your answer.

Do you have any recommended resources for asyncio best-practices such as this?

Comment: @NotaDoctor Unfortunately I don't know of such a resource, asyncio is usually covered by tutorials.